# ADO not retrieving data from database using a a filter defined by a variable

Tags: html, sql, forms, asp-classic, ado

I'm trying to write a piece of code in ADO which will display data from a database dependent on what the user has inputted in a HTML form. I've tried it by setting the input from the user as a variable and then setting my sql to query the database using this variable, however it is not working. My code currently looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>
Query
</title>
 <body>
 <form name="teacherReg" action="http://hr-computing/public/AlexS/Tests/UserQuery.asp" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="firstnameQuery">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
<%
Query=request.form("firstnameQuery")
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open ="{private}"
set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
sql="SELECT firstname, lastname, PASSWORD FROM teachers WHERE firstname = Query"
rs.Open sql,conn


%>
<%
do until rs.EOF
   for each x in rs.Fields
     Response.Write(x.name)
     Response.Write(" = ")
     Response.Write(x.value & "<br>")
   next
   Response.Write("<br>")
   rs.MoveNext
 loop

rs.close

%>


</body>
</html>
```

I'm currently getting the error

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'

[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.0.45-community-nt]Unknown column 'Query' in 'where clause'

I don't understand why it isn't working, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the value of `query` into the command

Try

```
    Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim Parm As ADODB.Parameter
Dim Rset as ADODB.Recordset

Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "{private}"
Set Cmd = New ADODB.Command

Cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn 
Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT firstname, lastname, PASSWORD FROM teachers WHERE firstname = ?;"
Cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
Set Parm = Cmd.CreateParameter("firstname", adVarChar, adParamInput)
Parm.Value = Query
Cmd.Parameters.Append Parm 
Set Rset = Cmd.Execute
```

You could make it execute by changing to this...

`sql="SELECT firstname, lastname, PASSWORD FROM teachers WHERE firstname = '" & Query & "'"`

but as everyone will tell you this is open to SQL injection and not a good idea